# iOS Frame Processing Time Computation

Tags: ios, cadisplaylink

For context, I want to measure the scroll performance in one of my views. Right now, I have a fair idea based on render cycle notifications using CADisplayLink API. **I wish to understand more accurately the time it requires to process a frame**. This is **different** from the **time it takes to render a frame which includes a bunch of idle time** after the frame has been processed; as frames can only be rendered at interval of 16ms.

[CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink?changes=_8) API allows you to listen to refer cycle of every frame. More specifically:

> Once the display link is associated with a run loop, the selector on the target is called when the screen’s contents need to be updated.

Is there any other public API in iOS that I can use to get this information?

Comment: Why not use Instruments?

Comment: @matt profiling the app on one device or many devices is not representative of millions of users that use this app. This needs to be traced in production and not instrumented locally.

Comment: Well, your question doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: I guess I should’ve been clearer. But it still stands that I would like this to be in the app vs local instrumentation.